# Numpy - More efficient code to calculate metric

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I am trying to implement this metric
[image]

I already managed to calculate NUBN with numpy operations so that is fast, but I can't find a way to escape python slow looping to calculate the DRD part. Here is my current calculation of DRD:

```
def drd(im, im_gt):
    height, width = im.shape
    W = np.array([[1/math.sqrt(x**2+y**2) if x != 0 or y != 0 else 0 for x in range(-2, 3)] for y in range(-2, 3)])
    W /= W.sum()
    drd = 0
    s = []
    for y, x in zip(*np.where(im_gt != im)):
        if x > 1 and y > 1 and x + 2 < width and y + 2 < height:
            s.append(im_gt[y-2:y+3, x-2:x+3] == im_gt[y, x])
        else:
            for yy in range(y-2, y+3):
                for xx in range(x-2, x+3):
                    if xx > 1 and yy > 1 and xx < width - 1 and yy < height - 1:
                        drd += abs(im_gt[yy, xx] - im[y, x]) * W[yy-y+2, xx-x+2]
    return drd + np.sum(s * W)

drd(np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(100, 100)), np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(100, 100)))
```

Can anyone think of a faster way to do this? Timings on 1000x1000:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure about `s.append(im_gt[y-2:y+3, x-2:x+3] == im_gt[y, x])`? It seems like it should be `s.append(im_gt[y-2:y+3, x-2:x+3] != im_gt[y, x])` based on the description and your other branch.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this can be expressed as a convolution with with some clever masking, but I need to be sure I understand what you are doing first.

Comment: Abs(GT-B) definitely means GT!=B. Conv is definitely the way forward here, like @MadPhysicist's answer. For what it's worth, NUBN can be calculated by convolution as well (if you haven't done so already) - simply use an 8x8 laplacian-like kernel.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It should be im_gt[y-2:y+3, x-2:x+3] != im[y, x]. As I already am filtering with the where different pixels (im_gt != im), that is equivalent to == im_gt[y, x]. Note that in DRD_k, B_k(x, y) is a fixed value, the pixel from im[y, x]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step in speeding things up with numpy is to break up your sequence of operations into something that can be applied to an entire array. Let's start with an easy one: removing the comprehensions in the computation of `W`:

```
W = np.hypot(np.arange(-2, 3), np.arange(-2, 3)[:, None])
np.reciprocal(W, where=W.astype(bool), out=W)
W /= W.sum()
```

The next thing (which is hinted at above with `where=W.astype(bool)`) is to use masking where appropriate to apply a condition to an entire array. Your algorithm is as follows:

> For each location that does not match between `im` and `im_gt`, compute the sum of the elements of `W` centered on that location where they do not match.

You can compute this with a convolution with `W`. Locations where `im == im_gt` are simply discarded. Locations where `im_gt == 1` need to be flipped by subtracting from `W.sum()`, since you need to sum the zeros, not the ones for those elements. Convolution is implemented in [`scipy.signal.convolve2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html). You get the same edge effects by using `mode='same'` and adjusting the edge pixels carefully. You can cheat and get the edge sums by convolving with an array of ones:

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

# Compute this once outside the function
W = np.hypot(np.arange(-2, 3), np.arange(-2, 3)[:, None])
np.reciprocal(W, where=W.astype(bool), out=W)
W /= W.sum()

def drd(im, im_gt):
    m0 = im != im_gt
    m1 = im_gt == 0
    m2 = im_gt == 1
    s1 = convolve2d(m1, W, mode='same')[m0 & m1].sum()
    s2 = convolve2d(m2, W, mode='same')[m0 & m2].sum()
    return s1 + s2
```

Comment: I am getting different results for this. A simple case:
im, gt = np.zeros((5, 5)), np.zeros((5, 5));
im[2:3, 2:4] = 1;
drd(im, im_gt) is giving 0

Comment: @juvian. I'll take a look at it later. I'm sure I did some stupid mistake. Or you can try to debug it in the meantime.

Comment: edited your version and gives correct result in my test case. Any way to combine the 2 convolve?

Comment: @juvian. I've rolled back the changes until I can inspect them more carefully. I suspect that there is. Will let you know momentarily.

Comment: @juvian. I can't see a way to avoid the two convolutions. If you didn't have edge effects, you could just subtract off the value from 25 at the locations that needed to be flipped, but you need to take into account edge effects. You can slightly speed up the process my modifying my original code to only compute `convolve2d(ones((5, 5)), W)` and distribute the values properly, but I don't think it's worth the time savings to do that.

Comment: I see, its already way faster than before so its definitely an improvement ^^. Thanks for bringing convolve2d into my attention